# Dynamic Pivot Error

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Need some help to run this query. It show error as "Incorrect syntax near '201401'."

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


select @cols = STUFF((SELECT  CONVERT (varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                 ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                    , 1, 1, '2')         

set @query='Select PO,ItemNo, Material, '+@cols+'
From
(Select PO,ItemNo, Material, qty ,PERIOD from sch_lines) myTab
PIVOT
( Sum(qty) FOR PERIOD IN ('+@cols+')
) as pvt'


execute sp_executesql  @query
```

Comment: You have to use quotename `SELECT  '[' + quotename(CONVERT ....`

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer but it would not fit into a comment. When using `EXECUTE sp_executesql` you should place parameters inside the quote not add them. Adding parameters exposes your code to SQL injections.

Here is the same of how to include parameters into `sp_executesql`

```
DECLARE @something NVARCHAR(20) = N'Hello World'

EXEC sp_executesql N'PRINT @something', N'@something varchar(20)', @something
```

For more information refer to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Based on that your code should look like this

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


select @cols = STUFF((SELECT  CONVERT (varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                 ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                    , 1, 1, '2')         

set @query='Select PO,ItemNo, Material, @cols
From
(Select PO,ItemNo, Material, qty ,PERIOD from sch_lines) myTab
PIVOT
( Sum(qty) FOR PERIOD IN (@cols)
) as pvt'


execute sp_executesql  @query, N'@cols nvarchar(max)', @cols
```